# Ubuntu apach2 because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

Tags: apache2

"because search permissions are missing on a component of the path"
seems to be a problem which happens from time to time. No suggested solution here did work so far so I a have to ask again what could I check if I get the above error.

```
namei --modes ./index.html 
f: ./index.html
 drwxr-sr-x .
 -rw-r--r-- index.html
```

on an Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `644` permissions are likely causing the issue. Set them to `755` and, if necessary, restart Apache:

```
sudo chmod 755 /path/to/source
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That should resolve the problem.

Comment: that did actually work. Can you explain why I need execution rights even for a simple index.html ?